# Why do I run noticeably slower than others?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I often play zombie escape servers where I've noticed that the majority of other players run faster than what I do, that much so that its easy to get left behind.

I run with my knife out, and don't usually have any lag (fast internet, low ping, fast PC).

Does anyone else have this problem?
Is there anything I can do to reduce the problem?

Thanks

Comment: type cl_showpos 1 if it is not 250 while you r running there might be a problem.

Comment: Are they bunny hopping? In the Counter-Strike series you can strafe jump back and forth to gain extra velocity depending on their server settings. I watched a few videos on YouTube and didn't really see anyone doing it though.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I've found is that the wiki for the mod states the following under a Guide in the "Useful Information" heading:

> **Strafe Running:** This move/technique allows you to run just a little faster than the default speed. By default the speed velocity is 250. This move requires you to look just a little bit to the left or the right (about 30°) and rapidly press left or right to gain additional speed. This will increase the velocity by about 10 (260). Look at this video to get a good insight in this technique. It's not vital to the gameplay, but this can be a decisive factor when searching for special weapons or items.

I'm not completely sold on this being the issue, but it's the only thing that I can find.  Here's the link to the page:

http://zombieescape.wikia.com/wiki/Guide:_Getting_started

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge, there is really nothing in the server side that will reduce your running speed, lets say you have your knife out, the server/game will have a set speed for that weapon and will not allow other players to run faster than you. However a possibility is that the server has different plugins with different upgrades? Well I guess you would know if you play it a lot but I am just suggesting here. Also lag wouldnt affect this issue either.

The only thing that MIGHT be affecting you could be your configs, but that is only if you changed it. I am not exactly sure about csgo configs because I haven't looked into it yet, so I cant really give you the specific line of config to possibly change, but you can try deleting your config file which should be located under [Your drive]:\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg

Delete that file, go to your steam, right click on the game, properties, local game files tab, verify game cache and that should auto download a brand new config for you, but some of your settings might be changed.]

Hope this helped.